# Insulating pex pipes in attic

Tags: plumbing

We had our house repiped recently after having many leaks back to back and discovered defective Nipco pex pipe was used in our home built in 2011. A lawsuit was already filed and settled and everything before we discovered this so we didnt get to participate in that and we paid for the repipe ourselves. Anyway, we originally had pipes underneath the slab foundation. With the repipe, they ran them through the attic. We didn’t really have to worry about pipes freezing when they were under the slab but now that they’re in the attic, do we need to do anything differently? The pipes are kind of sitting nestled in the insulation right now. Do we need to go in and wrap each pipe as well or should it be fine the way it is now? We live in the South of the US and we do usually get a good freeze once a year or so. Last year it did get down to close to 0°F with that bad freeze before Christmas but that’s rare. It usually gets into the 20s overnight during our winters.

What’s everyone’s thoughts?

Comment: I would assume that the temperature in the insulation transitions from attic temperature at the top surface to interior temperature at the bottom surface. 2 birds one stone, you might blow additional insulation into the attic. Technically the tubing should run through joists and attach to sides of joists.

Comment: Colder area, but otherwise the same. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/35788/18078