# Can I run 3 feet of water pipe in the attic for a rain shower?

Tags: plumbing, shower, attic

I have a shower that I totally gutted out.
I plan to implement a regular shower head and another rain shower head. I already have the majority of the work done and have only one thing left: to run a piece of pipe to the attic, then stick it out back to the shower (around 3-4 feet through the attic).

I have a couple ideas, but not sure which to pursue:

- To build a box in the attic (ceiling drywall, plus add a piece of plywood on top of the joists in the attic to create an air tight space for the pipe) and cover with insulation
- add some heating element round the pipe
- just leave it as is but make sure that the pipe is sloped. This will allow the water to get out of the pipe when there is no pressure (my distribution valve will leak it through the on-the-wall shower).

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: I take it that the attic space is not "conditioned" (ie, that it's not insulated space, and gets hot in summer/cold in winter)? I'd lean toward the first. All you need to do is keep it above freezing, and heat leaking through the ceiling might be enough to do that if you've got sufficient insulation above it. Finding some way to encourage it to drain (third choice) would also be good, but I wouldn't want to bet the pipes on it if avoidable.

Comment: Correct on both points, I'd make that your answer. I was going to, but you already got it

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10784/will-a-pex-run-freeze-if-its-in-the-attic-above-a-foyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right answer, but this is what I did:

1. removed a piece of drywall from the ceiling and cleaned all the insulation that fell down
2. built a small plywood box in the attic above the ceiling (only covering the top and sides, with access from below); insulated the seams with silicone
3. ran the pipe through the plywood box
4. re-drywalled the ceiling
5. added insulation in the attic on top of the box that was built

took 1 day to complete

Comment: Pipe slope also is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

where is the home?
he most important question:  Does it freeze in your attic?
Even if it freezes - if the pipe is beneath ample insulation it is ok - Unless you are on an extended vacation - in which case must leave the heat on low enough to make sure the house envelope does not drop below freezing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are running a pipe from the in-wall mixing valve into the attic space to supply a rain shower head.

This means that the water in this pipe will *never* be under pressure.

Make the pipe accessible and protected, insulate around it. This should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a tub/shower combo?  If it's totally gutted, what about adding a tub spout with a diverter valve? The vertical column of water to your shower will drain after every use.  As long as all the pipes in the attic are pitched, you should be fine.